# Q: go-jira: slice is not slicing strings in templates

Tags: string, go, templates, jira, slice

I try to get the date (2020-03-09) from "2020-03-09T08:09:40.000+0000" with this template line:

`...   [Ticket:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolution.name }}] starts {{ slice .fields.created 0 10 }} and ends {{ slice .fields.resolutiondate 0 10 }}   ...`

--> Invalid Usage: template: gojira:7:62: executing "gojira" at <slice .fields.created 0 10>: error calling slice: list should be type of slice or array but string

Documentations says:

> slice
> slice returns the result of slicing its first argument by the
> remaining arguments. Thus "slice x 1 2" is, in Go syntax, x[1:2],
> while "slice x" is x[:], "slice x 1" is x[1:], and "slice x 1 2 3"
> is x[1:2:3]. The first argument must be a string, slice, or array.

Here the complete template I use with go-jira:

```
@startgantt
{{ range .issues -}} 
[Ticket:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolution.name }}] starts {{ slice .fields.created 0 10  }} and ends {{ slice .fields.resolutiondate 0 10 }}
[Ticket:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolution.name }}] is colored Yellow
{{ if (and .fields.customfield_11202 .fields.customfield_11203) -}}
[Planned:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolution.name }}] starts {{ .fields.customfield_11202 }} and ends {{ .fields.customfield_11203 }}
[Planned:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolution.name }}] is colored LightBlue
{{ end -}}
{{ end -}}
@endgantt
```

Comment: What version of go are you using? Slicing strings works just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/SnHsZPqiao5

Comment: > go-jira 1.0.23
  
>go version
>go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64
  
>lsb_release -a
>No LSB modules are available.
>Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
>Release:        18.04
>Codename:       bionic
  
>wsl 1 (Windows for Linux) version 10.0.17134.885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slice` function was added in [Go 1.13](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#text/template), so if you're using Go 1.10.4 as you indicated in your comments, this function is not known to the parsing engine. Go-jira might add a function with this name, but that may not support slicing strings.

Best is if you upgrade to Go 1.13 or newer, and this `slice` function will be ready to slice your strings as can be seen in this example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{slice . 1 3}}`))
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, "012345"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SnHsZPqiao5)):

```
12
```

Comment: Oh... Got it...  Ja, I see, it seems if you install go in WSL and ubuntu 18.04 you get only Go 1.10... So I'll upgrade... Many thanks...

>sudo apt install golang
>Reading package lists... Done
>Building dependency tree
>Reading state information... Done
>The following additional packages will be installed:
>  golang-1.10 golang-1.10-doc golang-doc
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>  golang golang-1.10 golang-1.10-doc golang-doc
> 0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the quotes around .fields.created as you'll end up with that string, not the date you want, so that needs fixed but shouldn't cause this error.

This full template (with a few minor changes) does work with the latest go at least:

https://play.golang.org/p/fkK8DKyj9jy

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`[Ticket:{{- .key -}}:{{ .fields.resolutionname }}] starts {{ slice .fields.created 0 10 }} and ends {{ slice .fields.resolutiondate 0 10 }} `))
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "key":"key",
    "fields":map[string]string{"created":"2020-03-09T08:09:40.000+0000",
    "resolutionname":"name",
    "resolutiondate":"2020-03-09T08:09:40.000+0000"},
}

err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
```

Which library are you using to output this template, I assume text/template?

The introduction of the slice function is relatively recent but it doesn't give that error anyway. Are you sure you haven't redefined slice in your func map? That seems the most likely explanation as the slice function doesn't give the error you quote in any circumstances.

Can you try a simple test of that slice function with a string separately, like the play.golang.org link above, but with your template?

Comment: Hi, ja the quoutes was a try, to see if it works... Yes, I (actually go-jira) uses text/template https://github.com/go-jira/jira
Unfortunately it seems go-jira does not support custom template functions...

Comment: And your sample is my expectation how it should work... I'm not to familiar with go to find if slice was overwritten... At least in the code https://github.com/go-jira/jira/blob/master/jiracli/templates.go#L64 it is not listed... !?